# How to run VMWare Player on my Windows 7 machine without VT support?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware-player

I am using `VMWare Player v 6.0.2 build-1744117`, I want to run Ubuntu 12 using it, but it gave.
`Binary translation is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Long mode will be disabled in this virtual environment.` and

`This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.`

`This host does not support Intel VT-x.` error pop ups.

Is there anyway I can run VMware without VT support, as I tried to enable but found that my INTEL motherboard doesn't support it. Or is this any alternative of VMWare Player which doesnt land me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have, Windows 7 x86 (32 bit) or 64 bit?
 From the error message it seems you have Win 7 x86. I think you have got Ubuntu 12 64 bit. If your Win 7 is 32 bit and your hardware does not support Intel VT, then download Ubuntu 32 bit to run it in virtual machine. And as you are trying to run a x64 bit OS virtual machine in 32 bit host Win 7 OS without Intel-VT hardware support, you getting that error message.

---

EDIT:
Are you using McAfee Deep Defender? If you are using it, then uninstall it. 
Source: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2328692#2328692

Have you enabled virtualisation support in BIOS? If you have not, ensure it's enabled. If you are enabling it, then do a complete restart.

Comment: You mean to say on my Windows7 64 bit machine, I can create a virtual machine of Ubuntu 32 bit, even when my motherboard doesnt support VT. Correct??

Comment: To run a virtual machine in VMWare, you don't need Intel VT, unless you are using different architectures. I am saying VMWare (Virtual machine: Ubuntu, Windows XP, Red Hat Linux), because I personally used in my PC, which doesn't have Intel VT support. What architectures are you using in Win 7 and Ubuntu?